# How can I move a column with variable length in between one vertical bar "|" and "["?

Tags: regex, awk, notepad++, bioinformatics

My file has 4000k lines. I need to reformat it. So, I am trying notepad++ (or awk). The structure every line is

> acc|GENBANK|ABJ91977.1|GENBANK|DQ876324|pol protein **Tabulator**[Human immunodeficiency virus 1]**Tabulator**TLWQRPFVTIKVGGQLKEALLDTGADDTVLEEIELPGRWKPKMIGGIGGFIKVRQYDQIXVEICGHKAIGTVLVGPTPVNVIGRNLMTQIGCTLN

The characters among the 4th vertical bar `|` and the first `[` is variable length. Only I am looking for tips or where to focus to do it myself. I tried to print with *awk* but how there are one part variable in length, I obtained different results. Neither I can select by columns.

I would like to obtain a file with this structure

> acc|GENBANK|ABJ91977.1|GENBANK|DQ876324,acc|GENBANK|ABJ91977.1|GENBANK|DQ876324,pol protein

and other file with this structure

> acc|GENBANK|ABJ91977.1|GENBANK|DQ876324**Tabulator**TLWQRPFVTIKVGGQLKEALLDTGADDTVLEEIELPGRWKPKMIGGIGGFIKVRQYDQIXVEICGHKAIGTVLVGPTPVNVIGRNLMTQIGCTLN

**TAB** are in bold letters - **Tabulator**

Comment: What do you mean with "Tabulator"? Is it a TAB character? Do you really want the 5 first column duplicated?

Comment: Tabulator is TAB. Yes, the output need to be duplicated. The next pipeline works with this outfile. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do for the first file.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^[^|]+(?:\|[^|]+){4})\|(.+?)\h+\[.+$`
- Replace with: `$1,$1,$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # group 1
  ^             # beginning of line
  [^|]+         # 1 or more non pipe
  (?:           # start non capture group
    \|          # a pipe
    [^|]+       # 1 or more non pipe
  ){4}          # end group, must appear 4 times
)               # end group 1
\|              # a pipe
(.+?)           # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces (space or tabulation)
\[              # 1 openning square bracket
.+              # 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1 
,               # a comma
$1              # content of group 1 
,               # a comma
$2              # content of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
acc|GENBANK|ABJ91977.1|GENBANK|DQ876324,acc|GENBANK|ABJ91977.1|GENBANK|DQ876324,pol protein
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

---

For the second file:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^[^|]+(?:\|[^|]+){4})\|.+?\h+\[.+?\](.+)$`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # group 1
  ^             # beginning of line
  [^|]+         # 1 or more non pipe
  (?:           # start non capture group
    \|          # a pipe
    [^|]+       # 1 or more non pipe
  ){4}          # end group, must appear 4 times
)               # end group 1
\|              # a pipe
.+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces (space or tabulation)
\[              # 1 openning square bracket
.+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\]              # a closing square bracket
(.+)            # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]